# Using get_posts in SHORTINIT-mode

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, function

I am making a plugin which is called directly, from AJAX or similar. I'm using the `SHORTINIT` constant to speed up the load.

I need to use the function `get_posts`, which is declared in one of Wordpress's include files, which again depends on more include-files. How can I include and use this function effectively, without including a lot of other things I might not need, and that will slow down the page load?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Like a small example code of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to get posts. I have tried to include the file which declares the function, but that relies on a lot of different files to work, so it's not a good solution to include all of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can easily be fixed by including the `wp-load.php`-file.

To avoid loading in all of the files, do something similar to this:

```
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
require_once('../../../wp-includes/classes.php' );
require_once('../../../wp-includes/functions.php' );
require_once('../../../wp-includes/plugin.php' );
```

That's all the files you'll need, and can be a pretty effective solution if you know the precise path of the file.

Comment: Sorry Emil, but I'd highly advise you don't use that method. It's completely unnecessary and makes too many assumptions about the WordPress file hierarchy.

Stick to using plugin standards,namely actions and filters as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Why shouldn't I? Is this more resource-demanding than your solution?

Comment: The plugin will only be used by me, will not be distributed.

Comment: If it's just for you, then it's not really a problem - I just wondered why you'd want to re-invent the wheel, when WordPress gives you the wheel with chocolate sprinkles on top ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely trying to call `get_posts()` before WordPress is actually *ready* (WP loads plugins before it loads other libraries).

Wrap your code in a function, and hook it to the `init` event;

```
function my_plugin_code()
{
    // run get_posts() and what you like here
}
add_action('init', 'my_plugin_code');
```

Comment: The only thing is that it does not need to be executed unless someone calls for it. It won't be executed unless it has an action or filter attatched to it, will it? I'll still vote this up, I understand why it didn't work now. Thanks :)

Comment: All the action does is delay when `my_plugin_code` runs. You can choose to add the hook only under certain circumstances if you don't want it to run on every load.

Comment: I'll accept this, because this is what most people should use in most cases. Thans @TheDeadMedic :)